# What's point of 'create_test_order' in python-binance API?

Tags: python, binance

When creating a buy order, I'm using try-except block to catch an error like the following.

```
test_buy = client.create_test_order(symbol='ETHUSDT', side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=3.1031)


try:
    buy_limit = client.create_order(symbol='ETHUSDT', side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=3.1031)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I added `test_buy`  just because `[python-binance API][1]` documentation said so. But why do we need to create a test order?.

Is it ok not to create a test order? Or is that my code is wrong in a way not using the full feature of `create_test_order`?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to create a test order in order to create a real order, I think the instructions are just trying to be noob-proof kinda

Answer (score 2):

it's not a noob-proof kind of API, it's just a fail safe mechanism so you don't put an order which would fail as you are working with sensitive assets (money). So verifying that a test order would go through allows you to move forward into the real order, or handle the exception gracefully and communicate the consumer